# Identify Apple Watch Name

Tags: ios, watchos-2

Is there a way to identify the name

- of the current paired watch from iOS
- of the watch the watch app is currently running on?

UIDevice on iOS seems not to offer access to a paired watch.
WCSession on WatchOS is not giving such information either. Another Framework to think of?

**Purpose:** User having multiple paired watches and need to distinguish from which device the data is coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the current watch the app is running on can be accessed through the `WKInterfaceDevice` class:

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] name]
```

Although distinguishing one from the other using this method relies on someone renaming the watch in the phone's UI.

Because the name of the watch isn't really surfaced anywhere (bluetooth possibly?) it's likely that renaming may be a low-probability event.

Comment: Great. Regarding the probability: Users with multiple watches will tend to rename "XXXs Apple Watch" since they need to differentiate them in the iOS Watch App (imagine having two 42mm Sport watches).